# Refresh AngularJS ng-view

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have an application that's running angular as a front end MVC, but the back end code isn't exactly designed for it.  I've got a page that lists things that you can filter with search options.  All of the search functionality works, because if I hit search, the reload the page manually, the data I expect is returned.  My question is how can I make the ng-view reload the php file that is the "template".  I know this isn't best practice for single page applications, so spare me, please.  Is there any way that my controller on the ng-submit of the search form can say, "Hey, ng-view, reload your template."  It seems a relatively trivial thing, but the documentation has been of little help.

Forgot to mention that I tried using $route.reload(), but that just reloads the page as it appeared before the search parameters were added.  I could use $window.location.reload(), but that defeats the purpose of a single page application.

I run an ajax function that updates the search variables in the session, (it's kind of a dumb way to do the search, but the owner wrote it and I'm not going to step on his toes telling him it's wrong).  At this point, if you reload the page via F5, it loads the data expected, but when I run $route.reload(), it doesn't run the php again and get the updated results, it reloads the view as if the php never changed.

```
agencyMatrix.controller('singlePage', function($scope, $route){
    $scope.reset = function(targetUrl){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: targetUrl,
            success: function() {
                $route.reload();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't understand. Can you please provide some code?

Comment: Have you tried to clear the $templateCache? Maybe something like $templateCache.remove(pathInConfig) or $templateCache.removeAll(). Angular tries to be efficient by storing the template in the $templateCache while on the page so it doesn't have to hit the server every time. Refreshing the page effectively clears the $templateCache (and everything else that was initialized in javascript).

Comment: I was running the developer tools to prevent caching but I'll attempt that.

Comment: Caching in the browser and what angular caches are different concepts. From angular: The first time a template is used, it is loaded in the template cache for quick retrieval. I believe injecting $templateCache into your controller then removing the template prior to your $.ajax call will allow it to grab from PHP again.

Comment: I'll be damned, Patrick, that did the trick.  That's what I get for making the assumption that if chrome's caching was off angular wouldn't be caching either.  Make that an answer, and I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I  have used  angular with php  backend.

In my design  , for each view page  ,  there are view.php . ın this php file, there are json data for page and variables for page setting like directory of template html page.

my view.php file:

```
<?php $appName = "flySearhPageApp"; ?>
<?php define("PAGE_NAME",$pageName )?> 
<?php
<div ng-view></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var APP_PAGE_NAME = "memberActivateStatu";
   var response  = {};
   response.memberdata = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode(isset($memberInfo) ? $memberInfo : ""); ?>');
   response.errorCode = '<?php echo (isset($errorCode) ? $errorCode :""); ?>';
   response.errorDesc = '<?php echo (isset($errorDesc) ? $errorDesc :""); ?>';
</script>

?>
```

and the footer.php

```
 <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>online_reservation_public/app/js/<?php echo PAGE_NAME; ?>/app.js"></script>
      <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>online_reservation_public/app/js/<?php echo PAGE_NAME; ?>/controllers.js"></script>
```

and  my app.js

```
angular.module(APP_NAME, [
  'ngRoute',
   APP_NAME+'.filters',
   APP_NAME+'.services',
   APP_NAME+'.directives',
   APP_NAME+'.commonControllers',
   APP_NAME+'.controllers'

]).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/',{templateUrl:BASE_URL+PUBLIC_DIRECTORY+"/partials/"+APP_PAGE_NAME+'/index.html',controller:APP_NAME+'Controller'});

    }]).config(['$locationProvider', function ($locationProvider) {

}]);
```

Comment: I know how to do what I want id I'm building an application from scratch.  That isn't what I'm doing here.  I have to massage my angular controller to fit the underlying php.